# Perfect cubes form of $111...12$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I think $111..12$ can be a perfect cube, since $111..12$ is always divisible by $8$ and is sometimes $0$,$1$ or $8$ mod $9$. Also $111..12$ is sometimes $1$,$8$, or $12$ mod $13$.

Can $111..12$ be a perfect cube? If yes, are there any perfect cubes form of $111..12$?

Comment: Need $$(x-1)(x^2 + x + 1) = x^3 - 1 = \frac{10^n ~- 1}{9}.$$  That is as far as my thinking takes me.

Comment: in my experience this either yields to modular arithmetic or a very hard question.

Comment: It comes down to two Mordell equations, $9x^3-8=u^2$ and $9x^3-8=10u^2$, with the added condition that $u$ be a power of ten. Solutions to Mordell equations have been tabulated.

Comment: Have you tried to follow-up on my comment, Smart?

Comment: You have put a bounty on the question. If you are that interested i getting an answer, surely you are interested enough to look into Mordell equations, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the integer solutions of the elliptic equation $y^2=x^3-648000$ with the following two lines in SAGE:

E = EllipticCurve([0,0,0,0,-648000])

E.integral_points()

The answer is $[]$, which means the are no integer solutions for this equation. Combining this with what is explained by Gerry Myerson, one concludes that  no perfect cube has the decimal expansion $111\ldots112$.

Comment: Good. Does SAGE say how it did it?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson  Details on a  function can be obtained by typing in the function's name followed by ?. Thus, from the (long) output provided after executing the sequence

Comment: E = EllipticCurve([0,0,0,-4216,0])
E.integral_points??   one can learn that the algorithm employed to compute the integral points on an elliptic curve is given in  \textit{Cohen, Henri}, \textbf{Number theory. Volume I: Tools and Diophantine equations}, Graduate Texts in Mathematics  239. New York, NY: Springer, 2007.

Answer (score 5):

Partial solution:

Let $a=111\dots112=b^3$. Then $b^3-1=(10^c-1)/9$ for some integer $c$. Rewrite this as $10^c=9b^3-8$. We split into two cases, depending on the parity of $c$.

Case 1. If $c$ is even, then $10^c$ is a square, and we have $d^2=9b^3-8$ (where $d$ has to be a power of $10$). Multiplying through by $81$, we get
$$
y^2=x^3-648,
$$
where $y=9d$ and $x=9b$. This is the *Mordell equation* $y^2=x^3-k$, with $k=648$. Solutions of Mordell equations are tabulated at https://hr.userweb.mwn.de/numb/mordell.html#tbl5 where we find there are six solutions,
$$
(x,y)=(9,9),(18,72),(22,100),(54,396),(97,955),(1809,76941)
$$
Only the first of these satisfies the condition that $y$ be nine times a power of ten, and $(x,y)=(9,9)$ doesn't lead to a cube of the requested form, so we get no solutions when $c$ is even.

Case 2. If $c$ is odd, then $10^c$ is ten times a square, and $10d^2=9b^3-8$. By manipulations similar to those in Case 1, this leads to the Mordell equation
$$
y^2=x^3-648000
$$
Unfortunately, the tables don't go that high, so we'd actually have to put in some work to find all the solutions, if any, to this equation. Perhaps someone else will take up the problem from here.

Comment: $940751^2 = 9601^3 - 64800$ is the only solution below $10^{10}$ for the second case's Mordell equation$.

Comment: @Nilotpal Sinha : I think that the Mordell equation in case 2 is $y^2=x^3-648000$, not $y^2=x^3-64800$.

Comment: @mathlove Opps lost a $0$ in typing :)

Comment: @Gerry Myerson : In case 2, we have $y^2=x^3-10125$ since both $b$ and $d$ are even. It is still large, though.